# Prevent a programmatic click using pointer-events

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have this button which a user can click on, but under certain circumstances the application triggers a click event too. However, if the application is offline a class is added to the body and the button should be disabled. In that case it looks like this:

```
<body class="is-offline">
    <button>Click me</button>
    <script>
        $('button').click(function () {
            ...
        });
    </script>
</body>
```

with the following css

```
.is-offline button {
    ...
    pointer-events: none;
}
```

So far it works, but as I mentioned, the application can trigger a click too

```
$('button').trigger('click');
```

With `pointer-events: none` the `trigger` does a click and ignores the `pointer-events` setting. [DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/eduztr7f/)

Is there some easy way to fix this without the need for inspecting DOM elements for specific styling/classes or the need to propagate the offline-state through my application?

Comment: Looks to me like you're implementing functionality in CSS, while you should do that in Javascript or on the serverside. Why not call `.off()` on all elements to unbind the events?

Comment: I agree w/ @Midas, trying to do this via CSS is definitely mixing appearance and functionality. It's better to add a check in the click function that checks if the app is offline (better if app can come back online dynamically without page refresh), or as Midas suggested just unbind them all (better if app will always be offline until page refresh).

Answer (score 0):

as @midas mentioned, `off` should work, This code will disable clicks ONLY for the `button` `child` of `.is-offline`.

```
$(".is-offline button").off("click");
```

Answer (score 0):

You could check inside the click handler if your off- or online and do what ever needs to be done.

I am assuming that something needs to be done, otherwise why would you trigger the click event when your offline and you do not want the button itself to be clickable.

Well, here is an example, hope that helps.

```js
setTimeout(function() {
  $('button').trigger("click");
}, 2000);

$('button').on("click", function () {
  var task =  {
    "online": function() {
      alert('is online');
    },
    "offline": function() {
      alert('is offline');
    }
  };
  ($(this).hasClass("is-offline")) ? task.offline() : task.online();
});
```

```css
button.is-offline {
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button class="is-offline">Press me</button>
```